# How to delete a custom TextFormField in a list of custom TextFormFields without losing the information in the other TextFormFields?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to create a list of custom TextformField which can be deleted using a button with the Map function but the Textformfield is not deleting properly.

It is always the last Widget that is deleted.

Does anyone have a solution?

Est-ce qu'il est possible de  créer un objet qui peut se suprrimer lui même ?

Thanks !

Here is my test code

you can try this code in Darpad

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i5U1.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late List<int> _listID = [0, 1, 2, 3];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: _listID.map((id) {
        print(id);
        return TestWidget(
          id: id,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _listID.remove(id);
              print(_listID);
            });
          },
        );
      }).toList()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  TestWidget({super.key, this.onPressed, required this.id});
  late VoidCallback? onPressed;
  late int id;
  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() =>
      _TestWidgetState(onPressed: this.onPressed, id: id);
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  late VoidCallback? onPressed;
  late int id;
  _TestWidgetState({required this.id, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: id.toString(),
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => onPressed!()),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally for a perfect behavior of what I wanted to do I had to define a class TestWidgetData to contain the data of each widget TestWidget, including the unique identifier and the user name. When the user presses the "clear" button in one of the TestWidget widgets, I use the removeWhere method of the _listData list to remove the item corresponding to the given id, rather than removing an item from the index given. This keeps the state of existing TestWidget widgets when I delete an item from the list, rather than rebuilding them all.

Thank you for your answers they were very helpful!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   final List<TestWidgetData> _listData = [
    TestWidgetData(id: 0, textValue: ""),
    TestWidgetData(id: 1, textValue: ""),
    TestWidgetData(id: 2, textValue: ""),
    TestWidgetData(id: 3, textValue: ""),
  ];
  
  void removeTestWidgetData(int id) {
    setState(() {
      _listData.removeWhere((data) => data.id == id);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
          children: _listData.map((data) {
        return TestWidget(
          key: ValueKey(data.id),
          data: data,
          onPressed: () {
            removeTestWidgetData(data.id);
          },
        );
      }).toList()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final TestWidgetData data;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  const TestWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
   final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController.text = widget.data.textValue;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(controller: textController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: widget.data.id.toString(),
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => widget.onPressed!()),
    ));
  }
}

class TestWidgetData {
  final int id;
  String textValue;

  TestWidgetData({required this.id, required this.textValue});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to pass data to state class, you can use `widget.variableName`

```dart
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key, this.onPressed, required this.id});
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final int id;
  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: widget.id.toString(),
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.clear), onPressed: () => widget.onPressed!()),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass a key to your **TestWidget** to preserve the state object of every widget here is how:

```
return TestWidget(
      key: ValueKey(id), // a value key with id as a value for every TestWidget
      id: id,
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _listID.remove(id);
          print(_listID);
        });
      },
    );
```

you can learn more about keys from the [Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/@flutterdev) youtube channel